# Functions - Display vs. Execution console.log

Tags: javascript, function, console.log

I have a feeling this is really simple but I am having trouble finding any guidance on how to create a "console.log" statement that simply displays the contents of the function instead of executing the function below:

here is the challenge:

Create a console log that displays the contents of the function rather than executing it. For example, your result should be function add20 (num){ return num + 20 }.

Here is the code:

```
function add20 (num){
  return num + 20
}

// CREATE YOUR CONSOLE.LOG BELOW
```

How can I write a console.log statement to display the contents of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just log the function without calling it?

```js
function add20 (num){
  return num + 20
}
console.log(add20);
```